# Changing variables when backtracking

Tags: python, variables, backtracking

Let's say I have a function called `recursion(schedule)`.

```
def recursion(schedule):
    value = 0

    if ... :
        do x

    else:
        return recursion(schedule) and value + 1
```

Does anybody know how I can change this variable value? I can't change the variables in function definition.

Comment: I think it would help if you could provide a little background on what you are doing and why. Also, it helps if your pseudo code is as pythonic as possible.

Comment: Hi Thom, i'm creating a schedule for a football competition. I've created a pool of all possible and required games. I've also created a few constraints for the competitions via functions which al return the number of violations. The only variable for those functions is  the (partial) schedule. So i looped through the possible games, append a random game to my schedule, then run all the functions with my new schedule,  then count all the violations, delete that specific game afterwards and and pick the one with the fewest and add them . After all this repeat.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a global variable something like:

```
value = 0
def recursion(schedule):
    global value

    if ... :
      do x

    else:
      return recursion(schedule) and value + 1
```